# Cannot access a local web server within a local Wireless network

Tags: webserver, wireless-networking

I have a Tomcat web-server running on a machine within my home wireless network, and I'm willing to connect to it from other devices/machines. The problem is that the only way to access web server is via `localhost` or `my-computer-name` -- only from server's machine. The strange thing is that:

- I can ping 192.168.16.103 (my server's IP) -- from any machine
- .. but 192.168.16.103:8080 is not accessible even from server machine itself

I know it sounds as a basic firewall issue, but I have turned it off, and even (just in case) tried to switch all network-related shields of my antivirus. All the rest configuration (including wireless router) is pretty much standard, except for router's gateway ip set to 192.168.16.16.

At this point I'm stuck, and can't figure out what's the problem.. maybe some router settings that I've missed. The router is TP-LINK TL-WR741N.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT** The OS is Windows 7

Comment: If the port ISN'T "accessible from the server itself", then I'd guess it isn't really running on port 8080.

Comment: It is running on 8080. localhost:8080 works fine, ipconfig tells machine have IP 192.168.16.103, but 192.168.16.103:8080 is not accessible. It obviously goes through a gateway and gets lost, and I don't know why -- that's why I seek a help here.

Comment: What is the OS running Tomcat?

Comment: The OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Tomcat is not listening on the server's 192.168.16.103 address but only on localhost.  Take a look at the "address" field in the tomcat configuration and ensure it is listening on all addresses.

Comment: I already did, it's not the case.. By default Tomcat doesn't restrict to localhost only, and I have not changed anything. Just in case I double-checked server.xml, there're no restrictions.

Comment: What does 'netstat -an' show you about port 8080?

Comment: TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING, and several entries like TCP    [::1]:8080             [::1]:61146            TIME_WAIT

Comment: Looks like its only bound to IPV6.  try changing net.ipv6.bindv6only=1 to 0 in the config file.  More here:http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2009/12/msg01261.html

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Indeed, IPV6 was on. I've disabled IPV6 in Wireless Network Connection Properties, but it didn't help. Maybe there's some else IPV6-related configuration item I should toggle?

Comment: This isn't a Windows setting - Tomcat is only listening to IPV6.  You need it to listen on IPv4.  Take a look at the setting I mentioned.

Comment: It worked out, I was able to configure Tomcat to listen on IPv4 following your link. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: @uSlackr: either the server is listening on 192.168.16.103 or it isn't. Your first statement makes no sense: from the sound of it, the server was listening only on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and _not_ on 192.168.16.103 (in any form at all).

Comment: @David I'm not following you.  I said "not listening on 192..."  makes sense to me.  And as it winds up it wasn't listening on any IPV4 address.